# How to place a background image that does not stretch the height of a div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My current home page has a background image (multi-colored pencils) http://www.makeminepop.com

My goal is to place the same background in the corresponding place of my contact page http://www.makeminepop.com/contact

The resulting contact page should like like the mock-up https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20040939/contact.png

I've made an attempt, but from what I see, the two pages structure are slightly different, making it tricky.

The home page has a featured div (#featured). The contact page does not. It's this featured div that actually has the background image.

Simply adding the background image to the content div (.page-wrap.container) of the contact page does not work because it results in a stretched background taking up the entire height on the div.

Any help achieving my desired result with minimal structural page change and maximum browser compatibility is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I was asked to provide code; each page is over 750 lines of HTML, so it's not possible to paste the code. I have attempted to paste what I think are the salient parts. However, that kinda defeats the purpose. I came to the experts for guidance on what likely the salient points are. It's highly probable I missed something pertinent.

```
<!-- HTML for home -->
<body class="home">
<header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
</header>
<div id="featured">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-wrap container">
    <div id="main-content"></div>
    <footer id="main-footer"></footer>
    <div id="footer-bottom"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer-info" class="container">
    <p id="copyright">© 2015 makeminepop, All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
</body>

<!-- HTML for contact -->
<body class="page-template-page-contact">
    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
    </header>
    <div class="page-wrap container">
        <div id="main-content"></div>
        <footer id="main-footer"></footer>
        <div id="footer-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-info" class="container">
        <p id="copyright">© 2015 makeminepop, All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</body>

   //css
    #featured {
    background-image: url("http://www.makeminepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/pencils-452238_1280.jpg");
}
#featured, .post-thumbnail {
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#featured {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: With out any code we cant help you, show the code from the 2 pages and css, help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope there is some unique id to your contact page, in that case work with before pseudo selector for body directly. Code below, hope this helps.

Or you can also use this concept with the .page-wrap accordingly instead of for body.

```
body.contact-page:before {
    background-image: url("http://www.makeminepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/pencils-452238_1280.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chetan! That did the trick! I really appreciate the kindness as versus that of those who feel the need to be snarky and dismissive.

Comment: Welcome, glad this helped!